# How to listen and get data for changes in Contact Database

Tags: android, contacts

I tried to listen for any changes (add / update) in the contact database. And I also want to get data of a contact (ContactID, displayName, phoneNumber) when a change occured.

I have created a class that listens TestContentObserver any change from the contact database. But it only notifies me when the contact database changed without notifying me the data has been changed?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Contacts.People;

public class TestContentObserver extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver (People.CONTENT_URI, true, contentObserver);
    }

    private class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public MyContentObserver() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        }

    }

    MyContentObserver contentObserver = new MyContentObserver();

}
```

I want to get the data information of a contact (contactId, ) when a contact has been updated or added. Could you give me an advise?

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like this to onChange() method to get the contactId:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);    

if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
            return;

cursor.moveToLast();
do{
String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
}while (cursor.moveToPrevious()) ;
```

Hope it gives some idea.

Comment: @R700 How to did you solve the problem for update else if (currentCount == mContactCount) {
             // CONTACT UPDATED. }  This is being called everytime and shall I compare it with my stored contact list.